# number formatting based on vba not to have decimals unless necessary

Tags: excel, vba

am trying to loop through each cell and set the variable in a range to cell value that it's looping through the code as follows

```vb
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Selection
    Dim value As Double
    
    value = rng.Cells

    For Each cell In rng
        If Math.Abs(value - Fix(value)) Then
             rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0.##;[Red]  - #,##0.## ;""-"""
        Else
            rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0;[Red]  - #,##0;""-"""
        End If
    Next cell
```

but unfortunately it's not picking the each cell value in range and looping through
any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'If Math.Abs(cell.value - Fix(cell.value)) Then...' ?

Comment: ... and `cell.Numberformat = ...`

Comment: Yep! Shows how rusty my programming is! :^)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments above:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        cell.NumberFormat = IIf(cell.value - Fix(cell.value) <> 0, _
                                "#,##0.##;[Red]  - #,##0.## ;""-""", _
                                "#,##0;[Red]  - #,##0;""-""")
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: `code` Sub FormatNumbers()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim value As Double
      

    For Each cell In Selection


        If Math.Abs(cell - Fix(cell)) Then
             cell.NumberFormat = "#,##0.##;[Red]  - #,##0.## ;""-"""
        Else
            cell.NumberFormat = "#,##0;[Red]  - #,##0;""-"""
        End If

Next cell
End Sub